# WPF XAML DataTrigger ContentTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datatrigger, contenttemplate

I'm using a TargetType "ContentPresenter" style with DataTriggers to dynamically assign a ContentTemplate.

```
<Style x:Key="styleContentValeur" TargetType="{x:Type ContentPresenter}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding TAT_LIBELLE, Mode=OneWay}" Value="chaine">
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource dataChaine}" />
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding TAT_LIBELLE, Mode=OneWay}" Value="chainemultiligne">
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource dataChaineMultiligne}" />
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding TAT_LIBELLE, Mode=OneWay}" Value="entier">
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource dataEntier}" />
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding TAT_LIBELLE, Mode=OneWay}" Value="reel">
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource dataReel}" />
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding TAT_LIBELLE, Mode=OneWay}" Value="booleen">
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource dataBooleen}" />
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding TAT_LIBELLE, Mode=OneWay}" Value="liste">
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource dataListe}" />
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding TAT_LIBELLE, Mode=OneWay}" Value="listedynamique">
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource dataListe}" />
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding TAT_LIBELLE, Mode=OneWay}" Value="date">
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource dataDate}" />
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding TAT_LIBELLE, Mode=OneWay}" Value="grammaire">
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource dataChaine}" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

DataTemplates are like this:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="dataChaine">
    <local:TextBoxPerso Style="{StaticResource styleTextBox}"
                        HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                        TextWrapping="NoWrap" AcceptsReturn="False" AcceptsTab="False"
                        oAttribut="{Binding}"
                        Text="{Binding ATT_VALEUR, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                        IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnabled, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate x:Key="dataChaineMultiligne">
    <local:TextBoxPerso  Margin="3" 
                         Style="{StaticResource styleTextBox}"
                         HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" VerticalContentAlignment="Top"
                         TextWrapping="Wrap" AcceptsReturn="True" AcceptsTab="False"
                         HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                         oAttribut="{Binding}"
                         Text="{Binding ATT_VALEUR, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                         IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnabled, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate x:Key="dataEntier">
    <local:TextBoxPerso  Style="{StaticResource styleTextBox}"
                         HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                         TextWrapping="NoWrap" AcceptsReturn="False" AcceptsTab="False"
                         oAttribut="{Binding}"
                         Text="{Binding ATT_VALEUR, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                         IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnabled, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate x:Key="dataReel">
    <local:TextBoxPerso  Style="{StaticResource styleTextBox}"
                         HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                         TextWrapping="NoWrap" AcceptsReturn="False" AcceptsTab="False"
                         oAttribut="{Binding}"
                         Text="{Binding ATT_VALEUR, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                         IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnabled, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate x:Key="dataBooleen">
    <local:CheckBoxPerso FocusVisualStyle="{x:Null}" IsChecked="{Binding ATT_VALEUR, Converter={StaticResource StringToBoolConverter}, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                         IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnabled, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate x:Key="dataDate">
    <DatePicker IsTodayHighlighted="False" SelectedDate="{Binding ATT_VALEUR, Converter={StaticResource StringToDateTimeConverter}, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnabled, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate x:Key="dataListe">
    <local:ComboBoxPerso IsEditable="True"
                         ItemsSource="{Binding tValeur}" DisplayMemberPath="ALV_VALEUR" SelectedValuePath="ALV_ID"
                         SelectedValue="{Binding ATT_VALEUR, Converter={StaticResource StringToIntConverter}, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                         IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnabled, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

So depending on the value of TAT_LIBELLE, this selects the correct ContentTemplate.

I have a problem with the DataTemplate: "dataDate". The value of SelectedDate "ATT_VALUE" corresponds to another line of my source which has a value TAT_LIBELLE != "date".
I discovered this because I had an exception in the Converter: StringToDateTimeConverter.

How is this possible? Because normally only the lines of my source having TAT_LIBELLE = "date" uses this ContentTemplate !?

I do not use the right method to dynamically manage my ContentTemplate?

Thank you.

PS : Sorry for my english...

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a DataTrigger that sets dataDate, so it's unclear what you're actually asking about. As a note, an alternative to your large collection of DataTriggers would be a DataTemplateSelector.

Comment: Sorry, copy / paste error ... I just updated the code.
Thanks, I'm looking at DataTemplateSelector.

Comment: After several tests, it seems to work well but with a ContentTemplateSelector because it is in a DataGridCell.

Thanks again @Clemens !

Comment: ContentTemplateSelector is a DataTemplateSelector, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, it’s true :) https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.contenttemplateselector(v=vs.110).aspx